# SQL Server Management Studio does not load

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am working on SQL Server 2012 for the past 15 days it was working perfectly but now I am having an issue:

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application

Comment: Please understand that there could be many reasons for SSMS not opening. If you really want help please post more information we dont have privilege to look at your system so we all would be just guessing about issue.

Answer (score 12):

Please try:

> • Start regedit.exe
>
> • Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
>   Studio
>
> • Delete 11.0_Config
>
> • Restart ssms.exe

There is a similar problem in this feedback to Microsoft, please refer the below link..

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690773/after-installing-visual-studio-11-my-sql-server-denali-cannot-be-opened

Comment: Worked for SSMS 2017. I deleted all the 14.0 folders :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case have not done that yet, could you please try to perform a repair?

Another option could be uninstall SSMS only and install it again.

Hope this helps.